# How do you setup Laravel Passport so it returns JWTs for multiple types of authentication?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, laravel-passport

so I am stuck on this for several days now. My ultimate goal is to break down an old monolith application into a micro-service architecture and the very 1st step is to extract quite complex authentication into a new service, which will generate a JWT which the future micro-services will use.

I'm using Laravel 10 with [Octane + Swoole](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/octane#swoole) and also [multi-tenancy setup by spatie](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v3/installation/using-multiple-databases). Each tenant has it's own `users` table etc.

I installed [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport) and have it working with multi-tenant - each tenant can have it's own Clients and token management.

The old app has multiple ways you can login (username + password, tokens, SSO...), but in the 1st iteration I'm trying to implement username + password login only. I want to achieve this by creating [password grant type client](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport#password-grant-tokens) for each tenant , authenticate the user and if sucessful I'm adding [custom claims](https://github.com/corbosman/laravel-passport-claims) to the JWT and returning the JWT + refresh token as the response.

I sucessfully tested the whole flow and have most of it working, however I'm stuck because I don't know how to properly handle the actual authentication.

I'm using only `web` routes and the content of my `routes/web.php` is basically identical to [the one from Passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/11.x/routes/web.php).
My `config/auth.php` looks like this

```php
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

And finally, my `User` model looks like this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Constants\Connections;
use App\Services\UserAuthenticator;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

/**
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $surname
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $login
 */
class User extends Authenticatable implements NeedsTestingConnection
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'no_prefix';
    protected $table = 'users';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'password_api',
        'password_salt',
    ];

    private UserAuthenticator $userAuthenticator;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        if (config('app.env') === 'testing') {
            $this->connection = 'testing';
        }

        // Now this is the main issue for me I guess, seems kinda wrong not to use DI
        $this->userAuthenticator = app()->make(UserAuthenticator::class);

        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
    
    // configure custom username field
    public function findForPassport(string $username)
    {
        return $this->where('login', $username)->first();
    }

    // should I call the complex auth logic in here? Or use findAndValidateForPassport() instead?
    public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant(string $password): bool
    {
        return $this->userAuthenticator->validateCredentials($this->login, $password);
    }

    public function usersRoles(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UsersRoles::class, 'user');
    }
}
```

I found several other questions here in SO and at laracasts, but those usually implemented very simple logic in `validateForPassportPasswordGrant()` method or implemented custom UserProviders, guards and custom AuthUserProviders (but I think those are only needed if I need to protect other routes than those from Passport?).

So my question is how should I implement multiple authentication logics (user+pass, SSO...) with Passport?
I don't like putting all the logic inside the `validateForPassportPasswordGrant()` method, because imo it shouldn't live inside a model, but rather a dedicated service - but I can't (easily) do dependency injection in Laravel models and I don't like my current solution where I use `app()->make(UserAuthenticator::class);`.
Should I just call a static method from that service? But then unit testing would be troublesome.
Or should I completely ignore the `validateForPassportPasswordGrant()` in the model and create my own implementation of `AccessTokenController@issueToken` instead?
Or did I miss a massive chunk of information and need to actually implement custom UserProvider and override it in AuthServiceProvider?

As you can see I'm bit confused by all this so any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please keep in mind that bountied questions tend to attract "AI" generated answers, so watch out for that. Also you may want to reword your question to be more focused and less opinion-seeking. Your closing paragraphs especially are not very clear.

Comment: I think you can try a approach of creating a User Authentication Service and then Inject the service into the controller and you can update the config/auth.php and you dont need any changes in the Model i guess for now.

This will give you Auth Logic Sepration
And minimal effect on the current set up